# Micronaut: Around advice is not working for beans created using @Factory

Tags: java, javabeans, aop, micronaut

I have created [custom around advice](https://docs.micronaut.io/2.5.1/guide/index.html#aop) for formatting obj date fields upon certain conditions : `@XMLDateFormat(xmlTypes = XmlType.PDF, fieldNames = "testDate", oldPattern = YYYYMMDD, newPattern = MMDDYYYY)`

If I use an annotation on the method of the target class annotated `@Singleton` annotation, the implemented method interceptor is successfully invoked:

```
@Singleton
public class MyService {

@XMLDateFormat(xmlTypes = XmlType.PDF, fieldNames = "testDate", oldPattern = YYYYMMDD, newPattern = MMDDYYYY)
    public Foo buildFoo(Bar bar) {
      // logic 
    }
}
```

However, if I am creating `MyService` bean using [Beas factory](https://docs.micronaut.io/2.5.1/guide/index.html#factories) approach, the around advice method interceptor is not invoked, in places where the bean instance was injected:

```
@Factory
public class MyTestConfig {

    @Singleton
    public MyService myService(){
        return new MyService();
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why it is happening and how to make it work with beans factory approach?

The used micronaut version is 2.5.1

Comment: See https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/6352.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, if you add the answer to the question I will mark it as an answer to my question.